# Using BASH to create new elements in XML file

Tags: bash, sed, xml, array

So far I have done simple things in bash with sed, awk, while loops, etc.

What I need to do next is far more complicated and I'm not sure how to get started.

I have an XML file and I need to add element(s) to it based on the other information in the XML file.

What tools should I use to accomplish this?  *while loops*, *arrays*, *sed*?

1. Get a list of the composite ids and store them in an array
2. For each composite id, search for all of the individual ids that match up with the composite id and store the results from each individual ids in an array.

a.  If any of the individual ids have a  tag that is positive, create a new  in the XML file and set the  to positive.

b.  If all of the individual ids have a  tag that is negative, create a new  in the XML file and set the  to negative.

For example, this is an example of what the original XML file would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<waterSample>
    <HeaderInformation>
        <ReportSerialNumber>987754</ReportSerialNumber>
    </HeaderInformation>
    <sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-12387</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid></compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid>789-879717-001</labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Negative</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
<sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-12388</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid>78979</compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid>789-879717-002</labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Negative</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
<sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-12389</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid>78979</compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid>789-879717-003</labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Positive</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
</waterSample>
```

This is what the file would look like after the code ran:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<waterSample>
    <HeaderInformation>
        <ReportSerialNumber>987754</ReportSerialNumber>
    </HeaderInformation>
    <sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-12387</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid></compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid>789-879717-001</labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Negative</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
<sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-12388</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid>78979</compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid>789-879717-002</labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Negative</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
<sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-12389</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid>78979</compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid>789-879717-003</labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Positive</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
    <sample>
        <site>40</site>
        <sampleid>040-2016-78979</sampleid>
        <productcode>AQUA</productcode>
        <productdescription>10ozAquafina</productdescription>
        <testcode>Oxygen</testcode>
        <testdescription>Test for Oxygen</testdescription>
        <sequence>0</sequence>
        <sampledate>2016-05-27T16:03:00-05:00</sampledate>
        <prefix></prefix>
        <addendum></addendum>
        <compositeid></compositeid>
        <samplename>Water</samplename>
        <sampledescription>Tasty Water</sampledescription>
        <labsampleid></labsampleid>
        <receivedby>John Doe</receivedby>
        <receivetime>2016-05-28T10:49:43-04:00</receivetime>
        <reporttime>2016-05-30T11:30:11-04:00</reporttime>
        <result>Positive</result>
        <units>10oz</units>
    </sample>
</waterSample>
```

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools like `sed` and `awk`. Use something suitable for XML like `xmlstarlet`, or `xsltproc`, or a programming language with suitable XML libraries.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).